# Unresponsive script error in all browsers - need to identify script

Tags: javascript

Please can I get some help for my site www.spoiltpets.com

It hangs on an unresponsive script. I've no idea which script or how to find out. I've tested in Chrome and Firefox, both with the same results.

It seems to load one or two pages, then hangs.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You may use developer tools available with the browser to debug the scripts

Comment: Who gives a question like this a +1?! StackOverflow isn't a free debugging service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well looking at the javascript console in Chrome Dev tools shows these errors:

1. Directed Edge: BlocksController::NoBlocksConfigured
   shopify.directededge.com/blocks/compound?shop=site-1111.myshopify.com&templ…t=&product_handle=&basket=&tracking=8b952818-10a6-4caf-ab8b-16dbe70e3583:1
2. Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
3. FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling
   FB.init(). all.js:56

So it would appear that you have problems with your Shopify scripts and your Facebook scripts.

**Update:**

To view the Javascript console in Chrome Dev Tools you would go to View | Developer | Javascript console.

Doing so would show something like:
[image]

Comment: A print screen would be much helpful .

Comment: @Royi Namir - a print screen of what?  I copied exactly what was in the console.

Comment: A print screen of the tab in chrome which you investigated and how did you navigate to that tab. this kind of answer should also teach. not just answer. +1.

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I know which issue(s) lead to browser hanging?

Comment: @james-l wait for the printscreen.

Comment: @james - I don't think the Facebook issues would lead to the browser hanging.  My guess would be that because shopify is not configured correctly, that's the main cause.

Comment: I have noticed the facebook warning before, but never the other 2. Directed Edge is a recommended products app which has worked fine so far. So all I can guess is the invalid app ID, but I have no idea what that means or how to fix it...

Comment: hmm.. shopify admin seems to hang now. maybe it is a shopify issue. I'll ask in forums

Comment: The second two errors both appear on the same line (56) of your code, so are both most likely related to incorrectly setting up your Facebook app id.  Why don't you disable the DirectedEdge app and see if that fixes things?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help guys. the issue turned out to be a script I had that randomly swapped out divs with testimonials on them. When I deleted all the testimonials, I hadn't deleted the script! Sorted now, thanks again.

Comment: glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Not all problems on your site will generate a javascript error in the console.  Sometimes (as in your case) problematic scripts will just do  unexpected things.  So you should always use the console as a starting point, but be prepared to do some further digging...